# Initialize data qubits in the first step of syndrome measurement

Tags: quantum-state, error-correction, stabilizer-code, surface-code, linear-algebra

I saw many papers that say that in syndrome measurement of the stabilizer codes, such as surface codes and color codes, firstly, all data qubits are initialized to $|0\rangle$. What is the reason? I think that data qubits should be the code states, which means data qubits are the $+1$ eigenstate of all $Z$-stabilizers and $X$-stabilizers. I agree that the all-$|0\rangle$ state is the $+1$ eigenstate of $Z$-stabilizer, but not the $+1$ eigenstate of $X$-stabilizer. Am I misunderstanding something?